# Blur container background only

Tags: css, background, blur

I have a webpage with a markup looking something like this:

```
<body>
    <div>Some content</div>

    <div class="login">
        <form>
            <div>Some form elements</div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div>Some content</div>
</body>
```

My `body` element has a background image on it.

I want the background of the `.login` div to bee a blurred representation of the underlying body's background image.

The problem I had with the solutions found online is that set the background of the blurred div to the same as the body. The problem with this is that I use `background-size: cover` on the body element so I can't position the background of the blurred div in the correct position.

Another problem was that the content of the blurred div always had the blurred background overlayed.

Is the a way to achieve this either using plain css or with the help of javascript?

Comment: Try this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375311/div-blur-of-part-of-backgroung-image-with-css?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't with pure css but it can be achieved with htmltocanvas as described [here](http://abduzeedo.com/ios7-frosted-glass-effect-html-5-and-javascript).