# How to make background of div blurred?

Tags: html, css

Ok, now I've been searching StackOverflow for similar issues, but none of them actually fit my case.
So I have a background image that covers the entire web page, and in the center, I have a div which contains some other sub-divs (with a login form, some paragraphs, etc.)
What I want is to blur only that portion of the background image that overlaps with the div. Image:
[image: here]

So I only want the part of the image in the red rectangle to be blurred. If I just add a blur filter to the main div, it will just blur the content of it (the text and the form). Also, keep in mind that the background image is not the background of the div, but the background of the entire page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [<div> blur of part of Backgroung image with css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375311/div-blur-of-part-of-backgroung-image-with-css)

Comment: And this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583937/how-can-i-make-a-css-glass-blur-effect-work-for-an-overlay

Answer (score 34):

```css
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.61);
    
backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
```

**backdrop-filter** is a CSS property used to blur the background of a specified element or area on a webpage. It can be used on divs, images and other elements. It is supported in **Chrome** and **Firefox** 103 and higher. Optional **background-color** can be used to make the background darker. For more information, see the official documentation.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter

For Safari:

```css
-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
```

Comment: This is a great solution. However please add some explanation as to how it works and why it is useful. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: "Supported for Firefox" is not true (at least not without changing firefox preferences, which you cannot expect from a website visitor).

Comment: Now you it works with firefox 103 :) without changing any options in settings

Answer (score 3):

The duplicate mention by Arkej seems to fit your needs.*( [<div> blur of part of Backgroung image with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375311/div-blur-of-part-of-backgroung-image-with-css) )*

The trick is to use `background-position:fixed;` on `html`/`body` and the element to blur on top of it, so , both background-image lays on the same area of the window.

The duplicate uses an extra element, this can be a pseudo element if you do not wish to modify HTML structure.

*`Flex` can  also be  used to center body.*

```css
div {
  border:solid ;
  padding:6vw ;
  position:relative;
}
div:before{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  background:url(http://lorempixel.com/1600/800/nature/1) fixed center;
  filter:blur(4px);
  background-size:100vw auto;
  /* makup ? */
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 50vw rgba(255,255,255,0.2)
}
/* makup to center content */
html {
  min-height:100%;
  display:flex;
  background:url(http://lorempixel.com/1600/800/nature/1) fixed center;
  background-size:100vw auto
}
body {
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div>blur my background</div>
```

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/MpvRGJ

Answer (score 2):

Here, this example will do the work. This is also compatible with Chrome, Opera, Edge, Firefox, and Safari.

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.section-blur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(10px);
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container section-blur">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      Sül
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Sül
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      Sül
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Sül
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Sül
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It might work,

```
<div class="blur"></div>

<style>
.blur {
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-size:cover;
-webkit-filter: blur(4px);
-moz-filter: blur(4px);
-ms-filter: blur(4px);
-o-filter: blur(4px);
filter: blur(4px);
}
</style>
```

Comment: Where is that bluring only background ?

Comment: In that particular red triangle add your style as position:absolute; and add blur styles in it only. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, I was searching for the same CSS solution.

CodePen:
https://codepen.io/DesignersWeb/pen/MWqyqKq

```css
  .blur {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    filter: blur(13px);
    position: absolute;
    background-size: cover;
    background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1486723312829-f32b4a25211b?dpr=2&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=&bg=") no-repeat center center fixed;
  }

  .content {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: relative;
  }
```

```html
<div class="">
  <div class="blur"></div>
  <div class="content">
      <h3>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use **backdrop-filter: blur(2px);**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).