# add black and white filter to specific portion of a child container

Tags: css, reactjs

[image: page that needs filter]

In the photo above where the gray container is set I want to add a high contrast black and white photo filter.

Iv tried scaling the opacity and using the filter css3 property but have had no success. 
The body is the background image and the child container is the gray box. I want to just have the child show the black and white.

```
body{
  background: url('../images/wtc.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.profile-box{
  background-color: grey;
  width: 80%;
  height: 60%;
  margin-top: 180px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Is your image the expected result or is it what you get and dislike ?

Comment: You're going to have to give the gray box the same background image and scale it up to make sure that it matches the background. Then you can apply [CSS grayscale](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp) to the popover image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Easiest solution, but least supported: `backdrop-filter`

The most straight-forward way, is to actually use the rather new [`backdrop-filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter) property. Unfortunately it is [only supported in Safari](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backdrop-filter) (and Chrome Canary) so far.

```css
body{
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/uh5YLj5.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.profile-box{
  width: 80%;
  height: 60%;
  
  /* Backdrop filter */
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: grayscale(100%);
  backdrop-filter: grayscale(100%);
  
  /* Additional styles for positioning */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-box"></div>
```

The code snippet above will render something similar to this on Safari:

[image]

### Complicated solutions, but more cross-browser compatible

#### Using the deprecated `clip`:

An alternative solution that will see more support across browser is to use the `clip: rect(...)` property. This property has been, however, [deprecated in favour of `clip-path`](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/#article-header-id-1) (see next section for the updated solution). Since you have specified on your code that you wanted a grayscale area that is 80% in width and 60% in height (relative to viewport, so that is equivalent to `80vw` and `60vh`), we can tune the arguments passed into `clip: rect(...)` as such:

```
clip: rect(30vh, 90vw, 70vh, 10vw);
```

The coordinates represent offset from the top/left corners of the page of the top, right, bottom, left edges of the clip rectangle. To center a `80vw` horizontally, we need `10vw` on left and right (adding up to `20vw`). To center a `60vh` vertically, we need `20vh` on top and bottom (adding up to `40vh`). This computes to:

1. `20vh` from the top (this is the TOP border measured from top)
2. `90vw` from the left (this is the RIGHT border measured from left)
3. `80vh` from the top (this is the BOTTOM border measured from top)
4. `10vw` from the left (this is the LEFT border measured from left)

The image below will help you explain the calculations more:

[image]

```css
body{
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/uh5YLj5.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.profile-box {
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/uh5YLj5.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  clip: rect(20vh, 90vw, 80vh, 10vw);
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-box"></div>
```

#### Using the new property, `clip-path`:

Even though it is a more modern standard compared to `clip`, it still suffers from [non-support in IE or Edge](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path). The arguments of `clip-path: inset(...)` are not comma-separated, unlike that of `clip: rect(...)`, and it is slightly more intuitive to use because each edge is measure relative to the corresponding edge of the browser. In that case, using the same calculation logic we have established above, the arguments will be:

1. `20vh` from the top
2. `10vw` from the right
3. `20vh` from the bottom
4. `10vw` from the left

In other words, something like this:

```
clip-path: inset(20vh 10vw 20vh 10vw);
```

```css
body{
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/uh5YLj5.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.profile-box {
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/uh5YLj5.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  clip-path: inset(20vh 10vw 20vh 10vw);
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-box"></div>
```

Comment: @dutchkillsg Glad my answer helped :) I've updated it to explain the numbers/arguments I have used for the `clip-path` property (and created a figure to boot).

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is usually a pretty hard thing to achieve with css but it is possible. I think this answer will help you:

**TAKEN FROM** https://stackoverflow.com/a/19382357/8312881

written by [edensource](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2754447/edensource)

> If it has to be dynamic, you should have some trouble, but you can
>   have somewhere to start with this :
>
> **HTML**
>
> ```
> <div class="background"></div>
> <div class="mask">
>     <div class="bluredBackground"></div>
> </div>
> <div class="content"></div>
> ```
>
> **CSS**
>
> ```
> .content {
>     width: 70%;
>     height: 70%;
>     border:2px solid;
>     border-radius:20px;
>     position: fixed;
>     top: 15%;
>     left: 15%;
>     z-index:10;
>     background-color: rgba(168, 235, 255, 0.2);
> }
> .background {
>     width:100%;
>     height:100%;
>     background-image:url('http://www.travel.com.hk/region/time_95.jpg');
>     z-index:2;
>     position:fixed;
> }
> .bluredBackground {
>     width:100%;
>     height:100%;
>     display:block;
>     background-image:url('http://www.travel.com.hk/region/time_95.jpg');
>     z-index:1;
>     position:absolute;
>     top:-20%;
>     left:-20%;
>     padding-left:20%;
>     padding-top:20%;
>     -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
> }
> .mask {
>     width: 70%;
>     height: 70%;
>     border:2px solid;
>     border-radius:20px;
>     position: fixed;
>     top: 15%;
>     left: 15%;
>     z-index:10;
>     overflow:hidden;
> }
> ```
>
> **FIDDLE**
>
> http://jsfiddle.net/sE4Fv/
>
> **FIDDLE with greyscale filter**
>
> http://jsfiddle.net/sE4Fv/926/

Comment: Updated the fiddle to show the grayscale filter. [Working Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/sE4Fv/926/)

Answer (score 0):

Your `body` is ok, just the `.profile-box` needs some fixes:

```
div.profile-box {
  background: url('https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  // width & height etc...
}
```

Attach your background in the box as well and add `filter: grayscale(100%)`

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Thielicious/y6e5u1sc/)

Answer (score 0):

(you did not respond to my question in comments, so i still go with an average answer untill feedback shows ;) )

you can use an `rgba()` color if the matter is to darken your image.

A simple example with background or image to show the idea, a third example showing the use of the `grayscale(X%)` filter if the matter is turn blac & white the image:

```css
.filter {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.filter:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  right: 5%;
  bottom: 15%;
  left: 5%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.filter img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.filter.bg {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1.5% 2.5%;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/250/city/5) center / 100% auto;
}

.bg:before {
  display: none;
}

.content {
  min-height: 7.45vw;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
}

.grayscale .content {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/250/city/5) center / 50vw auto;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="filter">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/250/city/5" alt="my nice City" /></div>

<div class="filter bg ">
  <div class="content">Some content hover the bg </div>
</div>
<div class="filter bg grayscale ">
  <div class="content">Some content hover the bg </div>
</div>
```