# Blur <header> background-image, but not children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ghost-blog

I recently switched over to using [Ghost](http://www.ghost.org/) for my blog and by default I'm using the [Casper](https://github.com/TryGhost/Casper) theme. What I'm trying to do is blur the `site-head` `header`, by styling the CSS using `-webkit-filter: blur`, but when I do this, every other element also becomes blurred.

I've tried adding custom style attributes to each other element like `-webkit-filter: blur(0px) !important` in an effort to override the `site-head` blur, but nothing changes. I've also tried adding and blurring a separate element in between the `header` and the start of the first `div` leading into the other elements, but this ended in the same result.

I'm pretty new to CSS and Javascript and can't help but think I'm just completely overlooking something here.

This is the `index.hbs`:

```
<header class="site-head" {{#if @blog.cover}}style="background-image: url({{@blog.cover}})"{{/if}}>
    <div class="vertical">
        <div class="site-head-content inner">
            {{#if @blog.logo}}<a class="blog-logo" href="{{@blog.url}}"><img src="{{@blog.logo}}" alt="Blog Logo" /></a>{{/if}}
            <h1 class="blog-title">{{@blog.title}}</h1>
            <h2 class="blog-description">{{@blog.description}}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

And here is the style for the `site-head`:

```
.site-head {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60%;
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background: #303538 no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: see for a wrokaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168142/is-it-possible-to-use-webkit-filter-blur-on-background-image

Comment: I don't have a problem blurring the `background-image`. I have a problem blurring the `header` `background-image` along with every thing else. I don't understand what you do in that other question, would you please elaborate?

Comment: In fact, you should use pseudo element `:before` and filter it, not directly the HEADER. If you apply filter on HEADER, filter is inherited for all children and you can't reset it. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/juanojeda/T5j6H/1/  You could of course change your HTML markup by adding an element to HEADER and use filter effect only on it

Comment: So, you're suggesting to use something like `.site-head:before` to apply the blur, is that right?

Comment: Ya, that's what i suggest if you don't want to change HTML markup

Comment: So, I learned that you can't reference pseudo elements like `before` with jQuery, which is something I need to do. One last time, you've been really helpful. When you mention changing the HTML, do you mean adding an element in between the `header` and `div` `vertical`, then applying the `background-image` to that one?

Comment: Ya, exactly what i mean