# Blurring "around" text

Tags: css

I was wondering if it is possible to do the reverse of ... https://css-tricks.com/fun-with-blurred-text/ where I have non-blurred text but put some sort of filter around the text like a glow to make it legible.  However, I don't want to make the whole image blurred as in [Is it possible to use -webkit-filter: blur(); on background-image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168142/is-it-possible-to-use-webkit-filter-blur-on-background-image)

I tried the solution in [White blur around blurred background + maintain text non-blur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764207/white-blur-around-blurred-background-maintain-text-non-blur) but that didn't give me the result I wanted because it creates a glowing box rather than just the text.

So basically say I have a dark background with some highlights and light text... [image]

I basically want some what of a dark frost effect around the letters.  The background is doing parallax scroll so I don't want to put the frost effect on the initial position.

Comment: add a working snippet or a snippet or a pen to your post so we can help more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This may solve your problem.**

```css
#main {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/dquOn.png");
  padding:20px 50px;
  display:inline-block;
}
#main h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 48px;
  text-shadow:0 0 5px #f00, 0 0 10px #f90, 0 0 15px #f00;
  font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
  font-weight:normal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <h1>Archimedes Trajano</h1>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems to work only with "thick" fonts but not thin.  Marking as solution even though it does not apply to me at the moment since it does solve the problem.

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano Thanks, I have updated code snippet with thin font.

Comment: Your font is nice but still thicker than mine :D.  Lato 200 weight., I like your font though.  https://trajano.net/ shows its use