# How to remove white border from blur background image

Tags: html, css, blur

How to remove the white blur border from the background image?

```html
<div class="background-image"></div>
```

I tried adding `margin:-10px` in the CSS but it doesn't work.

```css
.background-image {
  background: no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-image: url('http://www.hdpaperz.com/wallpaper/original/windows-8-wallpapers-2560x1600-2311_1.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  left: -5px;
  top: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  position: fixed;
  right: -5px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0px auto;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/maio/8wq132nd/1/

Comment: Just remove all the vendor prefixed blur attributes? e.g. ( -webkit-filter: blur(5px);-moz-filter: blur(5px); -o-filter: blur(5px); -ms-filter: blur(5px); filter: blur(5px);) I'm not sure if this is the question?

Comment: Hope this link will help you,
[How to apply a CSS 3 blur filter to a background image that I am setting with background-image][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039765/how-to-apply-a-css-3-blur-filter-to-a-background-image-that-i-am-setting-with-ba

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have added overflow, padding and even margin, but still the problem not solved. So i tried to give the image tag between div. Problem solved.

**HTML**

```html
<div class="background-image">
  <img src="http://www.hdpaperz.com/wallpaper/original/windows-8-wallpapers-2560x1600-2311_1.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.background-image {
  background: no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;
  left: -5px;
  top: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  position: fixed;
  right: -5px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  margin: -5px;
}
```

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/2pgdttLh/

Answer (score 64):

The simplest way to do it is by adding `transform: scale(1.1)`.
Try it [here](https://codepen.io/AdamAshour/pen/qrYrNw).

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  left: 22.5em;
  top: 3em;
  height: 75%;
  width: 50%;
  background: url("https://s-media-cacheak0.pinimg.com/originals/ae/b4/c5/aeb4c53cab2b550187644af503a0f17e.png");
  background-size: cover;
  filter: blur(9px);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Comment: thought this scales the image larger, not quite perfect if you want the image to remain the same size and just want to remove the white border

Comment: It also creates a scroll bar for the overflow in webkit browsers that can't be removed even with overflow: hidden. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687023/bug-with-transform-scale-and-overflow-hidden-in-chrome

Comment: I did this, but on Android WebView there is scrolling. Even though I added overflow:hidden. I have a feeling it is because my background is bigger than the html element

Comment: Could you explain, please, the root reason of this glitch ?

Comment: I added `overflow: hidden` to the parent div to get rid of the scroll bar that `transform: scale(1.1)` creates.

Comment: using ``scale(1.01)`` also hides the edges. It just very slightly zooms the image. I prefer 1.01

Answer (score 52):

## Up-to-date answer (2024)

You can achieve this effect with just css by using `backdrop-filter` on an overlaying element.

```css
.blurred::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px); /* apply the blur */
  pointer-events: none; /* make the overlay click-through */
}

.blurred {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: no-repeat center center;
  background-image: url('https://besthqwallpapers.com/Uploads/26-5-2019/94041/thumb2-tesla-model-x-2019-exterior-front-view-new-gray-model-x.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="blurred"></div>
```

**Update** (8-8-2022): This is now also fully [supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backdrop-filter) in Firefox by default.

Comment: The brilliant thing about this is that if you wanted to only blur half the height of the background image for example, just set `height: 50%` on the `::before` class

Comment: thanks a lot !! This works like charm!! this answer should be accepted!!

Comment: doesn't work in firefox. backdrop-filter is not yet supported by default in firefox. manually we have to enable

Comment: @minigeek Yes, I have stated that already in my answer.

Comment: Nice, Clean and more control over 'filter' ... Should be accepted as Answer!

Comment: It should be noted that backdrop-filter was disabled/is bugged in Firefox. Some people say it works, some don't. On v105 it doesn't work for me, even with flags enabled.

Comment: working for me in Firefox 106

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:
Added two fixed images, one with z=-1, other with z=0, blurred the first one.

Comment: This approach has the trade-off that there's a new border around the blurred top layer consisting of a sharp version of the original image. But all the approaches do seem to have trade-offs!

Answer (score 3):

The blur adds transparency around the edges, so all you need to do is remove the alpha channel.

Here are a couple of examples of how to do this with SVG filters.

```html
<filter id="omega">
  <feColorMatrix values="1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1" />
</filter>
```

```html
<filter id="omega">
  <feComponentTransfer>
    <feFuncA type="linear" slope="10" />
  </feComponentTransfer>
</filter>
```

You can implement blur immediately in the [SVG filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35961398/13216566), or add a filter to remove transparency after the blur

```css
filter: blur(50px) url(#omega);
```

or pure CSS

```css
filter: blur(50px) url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><filter id="a"><feComponentTransfer><feFuncA type="linear" slope="10"/></feComponentTransfer></filter>#a');
```

Comment: This pure CSS approach worked for me, with minimal code impact. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a technical reason for `slope="10"` instead of `slope="0" intercept="1"`? Or is it just for file-size?

Comment: I didn’t delve into the documentation, I just saw such a method in some examples, so I took it, the math in the function uses both parameters (C’ = slope * C + intercept), but now slope seems to be outdated and can be disabled

Answer (score 2):

Use a SVG-Blur filter.

```css
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cfilter id='a' x='0' y='0' width='1' height='1' color-interpolation-filters='sRGB'%3E%3CfeGaussianBlur stdDeviation='4' result='b'/%3E%3CfeMorphology operator='dilate' radius='4'/%3E %3CfeMerge%3E%3CfeMergeNode/%3E%3CfeMergeNode in='b'/%3E%3C/feMerge%3E%3C/filter%3E %3C/svg%3E#a");
```

"stdDeviation" is your intensity.

[source](https://codepen.io/tigt/post/fixing-the-white-glow-in-the-css-blur-filter)

Comment: bad practice. it's too heavy for perfomance

Answer (score 1):

I added a negative margin to the container: `margin: -5px`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function I settled on based on @Prime 's answer.

In order for it to work the image must be positioned inside a `<div/>` having the `width` and `height` of the image (explicitly set).

```js
function addBlur(style, radius) {
  return {
    ...style,
    // https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters
    filter: `blur(${radius}px)`,
    // Works around the white edges bug.
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28870932/how-to-remove-white-border-from-blur-background-image
    width: `calc(100% + ${2 * radius}px)`,
    height: `calc(100% + ${2 * radius}px)`,
    marginLeft: `-${radius}px`,
    marginTop: `-${radius}px`
  }
}
```

Comment: but ads a white border in firefox annoying (had to add background color on body tag to fix)

Answer (score -1):

If the white borders are caused by the background color of the body, apply `margin: 0;` on `body` since margins are not `0` by default;

Answer (score -2):

```css
padding: 10px 10px;
```

Add this in your CSS to remove the white blur border for bottom.

Comment: You can white that shorthand like this: `padding: 10px;`