# Backdrop-filter blur not resizing when changing window size

Tags: css, reactjs, filter, blur

I have the following code to apply a blur `backdrop-filter` on a background image:

```
<div className="container">
    <div className="blur" />
      <div className="box">
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.blur {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/62/Kermit_the_Frog.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.blur::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backdrop-filter: blur(60px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(60px);
}
```

It seems to work well until a resize the window, the filter will not resize like the background-image. I tried changing the parent `div` to `position: relative` but it didn't work either

https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-tdd-b5u8ed?file=/src/App.js

[image]

Comment: Actually I have the exact same problem. I'm pretty sure it's caused by a bug in Chrome. A few months ago my exact same code still worked. Do you already have any workaround for the problem?

Comment: It's a known bug in Chrome. Check this out:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1417549#c2

Answer (score 5):

The fix for now, is to just add this extra style to the same class/ID that the backdrop-filter is on.

Works perfectly for me.

```css
filter: blur(0);
```

Example:

```css
.blur-section {
    width: 100%;
    backdrop-filter: blur(12px);
    filter: blur(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked in my case. Any idea what this does?

Comment: It's a Chrome bug that's going to be fixed in an future update.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1417549#c2

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a WebKit issue, as it does work fine for me in Firefox. I kinda solved it by making the blurred div a really big size so it always covers the entire screen. This does however seem to cause some small artifacts like flickering in Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

This will apparently be fixed in Chrome 112 (<s>currently beta</s> *now stable*).

I could reproduce the problem in Chrome 110 and 111, but not in 112, nor 113. Tested under MacOS.

The release date of Chrome 112 was **March 29, 2023**. See https://chromestatus.com/roadmap

So I guess, for *some* developers the correct answer is "just wait".

Answer (score 1):

adding another filter with a size of 0 will fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

`::before` is not a good option for this. You're better off applying `filter:blur` to the image itself.

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.blur {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/62/Kermit_the_Frog.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  filter: blur(60px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(60px);
}
```

Comment: I can't use a filter because of this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28870932/how-to-remove-white-border-from-blur-background-image

Answer (score 0):

I resorted to using the following code for now in case anybody is wondering

```
.blur {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/62/Kermit_the_Frog.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    filter: blur(60px);
    backdrop-filter: blur(60px);
    scale: 1.1 !important; // to hide white border when using blur filter
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0); // enable 3d acceleration on safari
}
```