# Can't blur CSS background

Tags: css

I've set up a very simple HTML page with this CSS code associated with it:

```
html {
    background: url("photourl") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
}
```

However, it doesn't blur. I've taken a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jLGFp/) example and tried doing it with a `div` tag instead but I don't quite see the reasoning here. Why wouldn't the code I posted work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168142/is-it-possible-to-use-webkit-filter-blur-on-background-image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use body to activate filter (also in Firefox) and set a background to HTML too so it is drawn by body wich is the tag that is suppose to hold all the visible content of your document.

When you set a background to body or HTML, it is drawn into HTML by default and filter won't activate in most browsers.***Run the snippet below and hover it to unset html background and see what happens .***

If you test on empty document, you also need to set an height to body, else it has none.

> https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#special-backgrounds

```css
body {
  background: url("http://dummyimage.com/640x480") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100vh;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
     -moz-filter: blur(5px);
       -o-filter: blur(5px);
          filter: blur(5px);
}
html {
  background: white;
}
/* see what happens when bg is not set also on HTML */
html:hover { 
  background:none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Stack </title>
    <style>
    div {
        height:500px;
        width: 100%;
    background: url("https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/750x422/394968_538b_5.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div>

</div>
Some Text
</body>
</html>
```

I tried this and its working fine.